# Address has balance on both chains… What does this imply in my case?

Tags: ethereum-classic

I just saw http://gastracker.io/addr/0xD0A70CF1C09E5824F6B0833688D29aE43AB48d86

Does this imply I can send ᴇᴛʜ if I have only access to ᴇᴛᴄ balance ? I don’t control the private key of this address directly : I can use it, but not access it or view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, The ethereum went through a hardfork occured on july 20th 2016 that gave rise to Ethereum classic when a DAO attack took place. Those who had been mining ether since then have been given with the same amount Ethereum classic.

The reason you are not able to access it is because you have stayed on with ETC blockchain and not in Ethereum blockchain. Due to this reason you can use the ETH in your wallet but your wallet currency is ETC and the Blockchain is Ethereum Classic.

Thank you

Comment: By accessing it, I was meaning private key. not balance.

Comment: you are saying that you have no private key for this wallet ?? if so, you will not be able to import your account to another computer.Other than that , you can access both etc and eth.

Comment: You don’t know your private key with a virtual wallet website. All you can do it to click on `withdraw`.

Comment: virtual wallet websites like myethereumwallet allows user to download private key file

Comment: not my wallet service.